# Converting from Hashmap to Array

Tags: java

I've been searching around for this but I can't seem to find a solution that works.
I currently have a hashmap

```
 HashMap<String,Float> map = new HashMap<String,Float>();
```

Now I want to access just the key part of the hashmap which is a column of strings. And I would like to create a new array of Strings from those values. If I were to just convert them:

```
map.getKey().toArray();
```

That would give the float values too in it's array.. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

```
map.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29.

Comment: Now that's an answer I can +1. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
```

will give you a string array with the keys in the map. Casting `map.keySet().toArray()` to `String[]` will not work because it returns an array of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a "column of strings" is, but what you're looking for is this :

```
String[] key_array = (String[])map.keySet().toArray();
```